# Best way to block a country by IP address?

Tags: apache-2.2, block, geoip

I have a website that needs to block a particular country based on IP address. I am more than aware that IP-based blocking is not a foolproof method for blocking visitors, but it is a necessary step in the right direction.

Since I'm using PHP, what I would do is use a GeoIP database like [geoplugin.net](http://geoplugin.net). However, I'm curious to know if there's a better way of doing this.

The website is on a shared webserver (I don't have root access) and it is running Apache on centOS. I guess my question is "can an .htaccess file be configured to block by IP using an external source to lookup IP addresses."

Comment: The accepted answer is no longer valid as of 8/9/12 with blockacountry being offline.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.blockacountry.com

Use cautiously...I'm sure there are plenty of people on here that think you are doing the wrong thing by blocking whole countries.

Comment: Hmm, not always. Sometimes you're mandated by law to deny access to countries. Like Pandora, for example.

Comment: P.S. With the script that they generate, you should really get rid of the `ErrorDocument 403` directive, or replace it with your own, becuase it redirects you to their own website and then launches popups.

Comment: I wrote this with this answer in mind: http://serverfault.com/questions/163502/chinese-hacker-bots-attempting-to-exploit-our-systems-24-7/163638#163638

Comment: Yes. This works quite well - and yes, I'm aware that blocking countries this way is not recommended, but it's a requirement and there's not much I can do about it. Good answer, by the way.

Comment: This is a great example of a non future-proof answer. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a [geoip module for apache](http://www.maxmind.com/app/mod_geoip), but the server admin might have reasons against installing it.

Comment: Ya, this would only be useful in a VPS or dedicated server setup.

Answer (score 0):

If you find the additional rules causing CPU overhead and latency issues, TechGuard makes an in-line appliance for [IP address blocking](http://www.techguard.com) of inbound and outbound traffic, including commercial block lists of millions of IP addresses tied to malicious activity in countries allowed by your policy. It does all this without impacting network latency or TCP connections, while automatically updating what is equivalent to 12,000 IP ranges a day.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Please read our [faq] in particular [May I promote products or websites I am affiliated with here?](http://serverfault.com/faq#promotion). Two answers and two recs for the same website is close to the line.

Comment: I'm with @Iain: possibly useful answer, but phrasing sounds an awful lot more like marketing copy than the voice of bitter experience.