# What is the best way to block IIS requests from a specific country?

Tags: iis, ip, filtering, country

I've been asked to do this before, but I just don't know an easy way to tell IIS (we're running 7.5) to block all requests coming from a specific country/countries. Does anyone know? I knew of an older ISAPI add-in called [GeoSniper](http://www.tometasoftware.com/products_geob.asp), but it dosn't seem to work in IIS 7.5.

Comment: Eric, have you searched the site, this question has been covered many many times before - take a look at this one for instance; http://serverfault.com/questions/166812/best-way-to-block-a-country-by-ip-address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for pointing out this question has been [asked](https://serverfault.com/questions/163502/chinese-hacker-bots-attempting-to-exploit-our-systems-24-7/163638#163638) [before](https://serverfault.com/questions/166812/best-way-to-block-a-country-by-ip-address). I was relying too much on the auto-suggestion bit. Following some of those threads, I'm going to go with [translating the .htaccess](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/557/translate-htaccess-content-to-iis-webconfig/) produced by [blockacountry](http://www.blockacountry.com/).